# Calculating travel time of an object on the inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Let's consider we have frictionless inclined plane and we pushed small object on the plane with initial velocity $v_0$. Travel time while going up can be calculated from following formula: $l = v_0 t_1 + \frac{at_{1}^2}{2}$, where $l$ is distance object traveled on the plane, $a$ is the acceleration.

Now let's consider objected stopped and started to slide down. Traveling time down will be $l = \frac{at_{2}^2}{2}$. $l$ obviously is the same aswell as $a$ (there is no friction, only gravity affects on the object). From these equations $t_1 \neq t_2$.

Now lets think from velocity point of view. In moving up case $0 = v_0 - at_1$ and in down case $v_0 = 0 - at_2$, $v_0$ is the same in both cases there is no friction, energy is conserved. Calculated this way $t_1 = t_2$.

I don't see where I have mistake. For me both logic is correct and valid.
please help me with the confusion, thank you!

Comment: The constant a tools you are trying to use are very sensitive to sign errors. You must use positions, not distance traveled. Also, your first equation is unconstrained and will not tell you your maximum distance. In the 2nd equation you assume that $\ell$ is the max distance, so it's a different situation than the first.

Comment: Hello, in the first equation I have an error, $a$ must be negative. I will try to put numerical values and solve it and compare the times. I assumed that object travel distance is $l$ = $x - x_0$ I don't think that is a the problem.

Comment: If you had been consistent with a coordinate system and used positions instead of distance travelled in both equations you would have seen the sign errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you made some mistakes involving signs.

In the first place, for consistency between the equations, the velocity should be written $v = v_0 + a t$ (notice the $+$ sign instead of $-$).

That being said, first fix some sign convention for the directions, e.g. positive upward the plane and negative downward (with this convention $a$ is negative.) Then, for the slide down, $-l = \frac{1}{2} a t_2^2$ (again, notice the $-$ sign in the LHS.) This is because $l$ is a positive number (the length of the plane) and a $-$ sign must be included to account for the fact that the RHS is negative, because $a$ is.

I believe that after modifying this, there should be no inconsistency anymore.

Comment: Hello, seems you are right. thank you